# Регулярные выражения(Linux,bash)

Tags: linux, bash

Выбрать из системного журнала события ядра (`kernel`), связанные с монтированием
файловых систем.

`journalctl | grep -P`, дальше не понимаю , что надо?
И журнал событий ядра `kernel`?
В начале правильно описал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
journalctl | grep kernel | grep mount
```

В выводе будет как-то так:

```
kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
```

**Update**

```
journalctl | grep -P '(?=.*kernel)(?=.*mounted)'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Выполненное практическое задание должно представлять из себя однострочное выражение
следующего вида:
journalctl | grep -P ‘<регулярное выражение>’

Comment: И еще у меня стоит ubuntu на вирт.машине, там нет команды  journalctl , я как понял там надо зайти в /var/log , там есть этот журнал

Comment: А что за версия убунты? Я этот пример как раз на убунте и делал. А так да, можно просто грепнуть /var/log/syslog (/var/log/messages - в редхат линуксах)

Comment: @КириллГорбунов добавил в апдейт с -P

Comment: ,Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

У journalctl уже есть куча фильтров

```
journalctl -t kernel 
journalctl -k
```

все события по ядру

потом можно фильтровать через grep, awk или less